# sending message with pushbullet via python API

Tags: python, pushbullet

environment : `Python3.6.1, windows10, pushbullet.py(0.11.0)`

Hi. I'm just trying to send a text message to smartPhone and PB software which is installed on windows via python-pushbullet API

Here is my code

```
from pushbullet import Pushbullet

pb= Pushbullet('o.R2pzLrVqMZhtiJdcJWF1DzlC0WaPm4bF')

push = pb.push_note("test_name","test")

print(pb)
print(push)
```

and results

```
<pushbullet.pushbullet.Pushbullet object at 0x000001DD4aaaaaaa>
{
 'active': True, 
 'iden': 'ujuOpFXwpA4sjzX6aaaaaaaa',
 'created': 1521021436.5832286,
 'modified': 1521021436.5979004,
 'type': 'note',
 'dismissed': False,
 'direction': 'self',
 'sender_iden': 'ujuOpFXwpA4',
 'sender_email': 'aaaaaaa@gmail.com',
 'sender_email_normalized': 'aaaaaa@gmail.com',
 'sender_name': 'yongeun yun',
 'receiver_iden': 'ujuOpFXwpA4',
 'receiver_email': 'aaaaaaa@gmail.com',
 'receiver_email_normalized': 'aaaaaaa@gmail.com',
 'title': 'test_name',
 'body': 'test' 
}
```

I guess authentication is done.

but after running this code, nothing happens to my PC and smartPhone. Is there something more to send a message?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It works by this way.

1. Replace pushbullet account with new one (for all devices)
2. Get new access token

I've re-tried with old account(did not worked one), but still doesn`t work. May be there are some bugs or else.